# Visual Studio regex replace repeated capturing group

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, replace, capturing-group

I'm working on a fairly large project (c#) and from place to place I have snippets that looks like this:

```
((int)foo).ToString() + "," + ((int)bar).ToString() + "," + ((int)zig).ToString() + ...
```

The comma delimited string has arbitrary length (average range from 1 to 5, but I'm not sure whether there's more). so far I'm able to find all the occurrences I want using:

```
\({.+}\).ToString\(\)( *\+ *"," *\+ *\({.+}\).ToString\(\))*
```

now for each of the occurrence I want to replace it with something like this:

```
{ (int)foo, (int)bar, (int)zig , ...}
```

replacing each occurrence manually is not feasible, is there a replace regex that does the job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do a find and replace in Visual Studio using regular expressions.

In a few words you need to use curly braces for tagged expressions and reuse them using `\1`, `\2`, etc.

Comment: Hi Ulises, Thank you for replying. 
the challenge here is that the length of the comma delimited string is arbitrary.
I tried to replace matches with this regex: \{ \1, \2* \}
however the asterisk got hard-coded in the integer array. the lined now looks something like this:
{ (int)foo, * }

Comment: Do 2 find and replace, one for \({.+}\).ToString\(\), then one more for \+ *"," *\+

Comment: In Visual Studio 2012 they changed it from curly braces to parantheses for groups and from \1, \2 to $1 and $2, which is more similar to normal regex styles.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but it sounds like you've already got your answer...  Use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(string, string)`. If you need fine-grained control, consider wrapping your captures with names: `\((?<foo>.+)\)` (or use indexes).  With those captures you can do the replacements manually if need be by looping through the matches and then iterating over the captures.

Comment: Hi RayB64, Thank you for replying. I'm trying to use the find and replace tool in Visual Studio and the project is written in c#, not using c# to do the find and replace